# Ask the direction of Principal axis theorem

Tags: linear-algebra

I can understand the half-length in the direction $\textbf{e}_1$ is $c/\sqrt{\lambda _1}$ , given $c^2 = \lambda_1 y_1^2 + \lambda_2 y_2^2 $, where $y_1 = x'e_1$ and $y_2=x'e_2$.

But I don't understand why we can safely claim that the direction of hyperellipsoid is just eigenvectors $e_1, e_2$?

Comment: What hyperellipsoid ?

Comment: You can think of ellipsoid if p=2 dimension.

Comment: I don't think the question is correct.  Please review the source of the question, and include what is given or assumed and the statement or result that has to be validated.